# SSH command in node js retries abruptly

Tags: node.js

I have a node app, where I need to retry a certain function if it fails first time.
However the SSH command runs more than it has to. I am still not able to understand why does the SSH command run more than it has to. It is like for every time it has to run, it runs like 3 times, and then that multiplies the next time it has to retry. Any solution?
Below is the code and output.
Node version is 6.9
Code :

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var ssh = new SSH({
host: ip,
user: id,
pass: pwd
 });
 var retrys=1;
 var maxretry=6;
 var err;
 lsCheck();



function lsCheck(){
console.log('in ls');
if(retrys < maxretry){
    console.log('try attempt '+retrys);

 //to check if the destination folder is emtpy or not.
 ssh.exec("cd path;ls | wc -l",{
 out: function(stdout) {
    console.log('called server for folder list');
 if(stdout == 0){
     //if emtpy , the xfer the package
   .. code

  }
  else{
   console.log('not good to xfer, retry in 5');
   err = 'retry Attempt maxed out';
     //if not emtpy , the wait 5 seconds and try again.
     setTimeout(() => {
         console.log('retrys');
                        retrys=retrys+1;
         console.log(retrys);
         lsCheck();      
        },5000);

  }

  },
  err:function(err){
     console.log(err);
     res.send('Failure');
     res.end('OK')
   }
  }).start();
}
 else{
    res.send(err);
    res.end('OK');
  }

 }
```

Output

```
in ls
try attempt 1
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
retrys
2
in ls
try attempt 2
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
retrys
3
in ls
try attempt 3
retrys
4
in ls
try attempt 4
retrys
5
in ls
try attempt 5
retrys
6
in ls
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
called server for folder list
not good to xfer, retry in 5
retrys
7
in ls
```